# Microscopes magnification clarification

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses, microscopy

[image]

[image]

Why is the linear magnification $m_{obj}$ defined as

$\frac{-d_i^{obj}}{d_o^{obj}}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linear magnification is not **defined** by that formula. The definition is simply the ratio between the size of the imge and the size of the object. This is valid for any optical device.
In the case of a single lens, it can be shown, from the geometry of the light rays, and in the paraxial approximation, that the magnification is related to the distance object and distance image by the negative of their ratio, as you write in the OP.
The objective of the microscope is a convergent lens (actually a system of lenses but here you have a simplified model) so the formula for convergent lens applies appies to its magnification.